# Converting Physical Exchange 2007 Mailbox servers to VMWare VSphere Virtual Servers

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, vmware-vsphere, vmware-converter, physical-to-virtual

Any recommendations or help would be much appreciated for converting two Exchange 2007 Maibox Servers to VSphere Virtual Servers.

I have tried more times than I would like to admit with Vcenter Converter and even spent about 7 hours with support from VMWare trying to get it to work unsuccessfully.

I am at a point where I would like to make some kind of backup/restore solution work, but not sure how exactly to do that and can't find great documents or help out there to do this type of operation.

Aside from a backup/restore method, I think my only option is to build up new virtual servers from scratch and attach the db's.

Our Backup solution is NetBackup 6.5.

My Exchange Mailbox servers(2) are running on Server 2003 R2 and they have Exchange Server 2007 SP2 Rollup 4.

Also I don't believe they are clustered as each one has unique mailboxes.

Comment: Where or why is the vSphere Converter failing?

Comment: All 4 partitions were being converted successfully, but ultimately we never got it to boot. It seems that there was drive driver issues.

Answer (score 5):

simply don't.  Add 2 more exchange servers to the environment and move the mailboxes to the new servers.  After all moves are complete you can remove the old servers.  While it is likely possible to p2v the servers, there is absolutely no upside to doing so and a hole host of reasons not to.  Do not attach the old DBs as that can also cause issues.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Jim - Exchange 2007 has a mechanism for easily moving mailboxes from one mailbox server to another. It's reliable, well documented, scriptable and supported. Why not take advantage of it?

Comment: Good advice. Much better solution.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I will follow it. One of the things I'm concerned about is not quite getting everything on the new servers setup like the old ones were. Is there documentation that could be pointed out to help with this process? Any advice with moving the mailboxes would be good, but especially documentation about everything else would be appreciated. Thanks!